# Wordpress SQL insert string into custom fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have several thousand posts in a custom post type called `clothing` which have a custom field called `wpcf-translation`

I need to insert a string into every single post's `wpcf-translation` custom field.

But I couldn't find anything on the internet. So my question is, is there an SQL query I can use to insert a string into every single post's custom field `wpcf-translation` in custom post type `clothing`?

Thanks

Comment: Is the wpcf-translation a 'serialized' field?  Can you give an example of a row from that field?

Comment: I don't think the field is serialized. I'm really new to SQL queries, what sort of information are you looking for in the example row?

Comment: I am fairly certain you are using the "Types" plugin to create your custom fields?  From a cursory look I found that indeed many of the fields in Types are serialized data, you may find this post on the Wordpress Codex helpful - 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-types-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-management-wpcf-on-custom-fields

Comment: Yea I am using the Types plugin, so if the fields are serialized data, is there a query I can use to insert a string into these fields?

Comment: Frankly I suggest using the Serialized Data Search and Replace for Wordpress if you don't know what serialized data is.  Basically you will have to unserialize the data, and then reserialize it and then insert.  Any direct db manipulation on those fields may be interpreted as 'corrupted' and not work.  Serialized data means that every string or piece of data has a set length, and if that length is exceeded by the field's actual content it assumes it is corrupted.

The script referred to can be found - https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: The thing is, I'm also using a plugin called WPAllimport to import the posts, in the importing dashboard there is an option to have the field be 'Serialized'. By default this option is unchecked. So I'm assuming that the imported posts fields aren't serialized.

Comment: I have my database backed up already and if anything goes wrong I can restore quickly. Would you have a query where I can test if it works?

Comment: Okay actually I've installed the Serialized Data Search and Replace for Wordpress, but I don't see a way to actually insert string's into a custom field. I do see options to search and replace though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67075/discussion-between-joshua-chavanne-and-user2028856).

Comment: Upon looking at the field it was not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment :  *I don't think the field is serialized.*  , the following should get the job done

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'clothing',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $query->have_posts() ) : if( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-translation' , 'your string here');
else :
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
endif; 

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Ensure that you have a backup in place in case things go awry. Code created on the fly, so might need some fine tuning.